# Error while converting a sparse tensor to a dense tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to convert a sparse tensor to a dense tensor.

I try to run this code:

```
from tensorflow import sparse

# Create sparse tensor
var_34 = sparse.SparseTensor(indices = [[1,3], [7, 1]],
 values = [11, 56],
  dense_shape = [5, 6])

# to_dense() to convert a sparse tensor to a dense tensor
var_35 = sparse.to_dense(var_34)
var_35
```

But I am getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a37ec05d7b67> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 
      9 # to_dense() to convert a sparse tensor to a dense tensor
---> 10 var_35 = sparse.to_dense(var_34)
     11 var_35

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6654 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   6655   e.message += (" name: " + str(name if name is not None else ""))
-> 6656   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   6657 
   6658 

InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__SparseToDense_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} indices[1] = [7,1] is out of bounds: need 0 <= index < [5,6] [Op:SparseToDense] name:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it's all on the error message, on the last line

`[7,1] is out of bounds: need 0 <= index < [5,6]`

```
sparse.SparseTensor(indices = [[1,3], [7, 1]],
 values = [11, 56],
  dense_shape = [5, 6])
```

You get a shape of [5, 6] and try to put the value 56 into the coordinate [7, 1], as 7 >= 5 you can't.

Try out *(I just change the coordinate of the value 56 here)*

```
from tensorflow import sparse

# Create sparse tensor
var_34 = sparse.SparseTensor(indices = [[1,3], [4, 1]],
 values = [11, 56],
  dense_shape = [5, 6])

print(var_34)

# to_dense() to convert a sparse tensor to a dense tensor
var_35 = sparse.to_dense(var_34)
print(var_35)
```

It would perfectly work.

```
[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0 11  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0 56  0  0  0  0]]
```

The value 56 is at the coordinate [4, 1]

To generalise, and as I understand the function:

- dense_shape: The shape of you're sparse array
- indices: The coordinate of you're futurs values
- values: The value to place to your given coordinate